# Excel Handling Spaces in Name Manager with INDIRECT/SUBSTITUTE

Tags: excel

I have five columns of dropdown boxes, and each is conditional on the last.  So, if someone picks 'Facility' in the first column they'll get a series of dropdown options in the next column that only accompany 'Facility' and so on and so on.  In the third column I have an option called 'Substructure Drainage'.  When I create a new object in Name Manager I understand that I must use spaces and call it 'Substructure_Drainage'.  So now when someone picks Substructure Drainage they're not getting dropdown options in the next column.  I've tried using indirect/substitute `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(C3,"_",""))` but with no luck.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to use this probably :`=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C3,"&"," ")," ","_"))` Look **[Here](https://imgur.com/gallery/N4weTIF)**

Comment: If the defined name is `Substructure_Drainage`, then it should be `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(C3," ","_"))` , that is, replacing space with underscore.

Comment: The formula which I have given it will work for `Substructure Drainage` and as well as `Superstructure & Appurtenances` note that you need to remove both spaces as well as `&` Excel naming rule states that you cant contain spaces and most punctuation characters.

Comment: Thanks @MayukhBhattacharya how would I also handle the fact that I have a choice which becomes a header with parenthesis like 'Fire Protection (Building)'

Comment: @GreggRosenstein sorry for late response. For now you have to use multiple `SUBSTITUTE()` functions there is no option to use `LAMBDA()` function to remove multiple substituting characters. That said, the formula will be `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C3,"&"," ")," ","_"),")","("),"(",))`